# Python creating a variable dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, redmine, redmine-api

I'm not a python expert and I encountered an issue working with an already existing API (redmine API but it's not really a problem with the API).

The API give me a method which enable me to get data from a database using a filter to get the type of data I need. For example, if i want a data with a value of "value" in the field which have the id = 20

```
object.issue.filter(cf_20 = value)
```

It works fine. However the id of the field I need to get can vary. So I have a variable

```
fieldID
```

which contains the id of the field I need to filter (20 in my example).

How can I give to object.issue.filter the good value (depending on the variable fieldID) ? Something like

```
object.issue.filter(cf_<fieldID> = value)
```

where  would be replaced by the value of fieldID

Comment: take a look at keyword-arguments for functions: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/228/functions/932/defining-a-function-with-an-arbitrary-number-of-arguments i.e. you can dynamically create a dictionary with your custom keys and values and pour it into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary `{"cf_" + str(fieldID): value}` of your intended `filter` arguments and then use `**` to unpack them in the method call:

```
object.issue.filter(**{"cf_" + str(fieldID): value})
```